# How to draw on Border of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, ribbon

I am building a Ribbon Frame similar to the one below but I don't know how to draw on the border/ title bar of the JFrame. I need to draw an elipse on the top-left corner on the JFrame border/ title bar, similar to the one below. Is there any way i could do this in Java, if not how would I go about creating an aero style border.

[image: Sample Border Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done using the... Wait for it... The `JRibbonFrame`. In order to use it however, you'll need to get the Flamingo Framework. It's pretty simple to use! [here's](http://blog.frankel.ch/flamingo-tutorial) a working example. Of course, you'll have to [download](https://github.com/kirillcool/flamingo) Flamingo to get things working.

[image]

It doesn't look like a "real" ribbon frame, though.

[image]

I'm not sure, but apparently you can end up with something like this too.

The project is dead by the looks of it (updated 3 years ago), so I would only recommend it if you used `setUndecorated();` on your frame. This will hide the title bar. Then, you could add custom buttons that would replace the buttons on the title bar (close, minimize, maximize).

You could also [create a custom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409497/2607904) `JFrame` appearing like a ribbon frame which is the most advanced and most rewarding option. Using this, you could end up with something that might fit your needs more accurately. Hope you liked my answer! :)